# Bypass the login control authentication, but getting the permissions same like it

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

In my project I have used Login control to authenticate the users and have set the permissions in web.config like this:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>
 <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="*"/>
 </authorization>
```

But according the new requirement I have set an alternative of authentication through an api
but after authenticating through api when I redirect the user to the home page it redirects to the Login page. Is there any way I can authenticate the user without using the Login control in this particular case without altering the web.config setting. I can't show a user a login control when he chooses to get authenticated through api.

Comment: But how do you authentiate through api? The asp.net authentication based on cookies, that sent to the client browser and the browser send it back in every requst.

Comment: @Péter thanks for your reply, can I manually set cookies after I am sure of the authenticity from the fetched values of api callback.  What you pointed out is with forms authentication I think ?

Comment: The main question is still that how the user authenticate? Via a desktop application? Or some else method? The problem is that the cookies is move between the server and the client browser. Maybe to achieve this you have to implement your own membership provider, that and be called from outside.

Comment: @Péter isn't there any way I can call onauthenticate event of login control without showing and clicking on it. Is it possible to do so